# Simpler or shorter way to simplify expression $(16^{2} \times 64^{3})\div1024^{2}$ for a power

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am studying about powers for a discipline in college and the teacher asked me to simplify the following expression to transform it into the form of a single power,

$$
(16^{2} \times 64^{3})\div1024^{2}
$$

I can simplify to,

$$
2^{6}
$$

But, take many steps to get this result,

$$
(16^{2} \times 64^{3})\div1024^{2} \\ \implies(16\times16)\times(64\times64\times64)\div(1024\times1024) \\ \implies 256 \times262144\div1048576\\ \implies67108864\div1048576=64\\ 64\implies2^{6} \\ (16^{2} \times 64^{3})\div1024^{2} \implies 2^{6}
$$

However I would like to know if there is a shorter or simpler way to simplify expression $(16^{2} \times 64^{3})\div1024^{2}$ ?

Comment: Just a note: You should use the equals sign ($=$) instead of the implication arrow.

Comment: @red_trumpet is there any question on how to use the implied symbol? I am still learning.

Comment: @gato See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1957893/350028).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
& (16^2 \times 64^3)\div1024^2 \\[10pt]
= {} & (2^4)^2 \times (2^6)^3 \div (2^{10})^2 \\[10pt]
= {} & 2^8 \times 2^{18} \div 2^{20} \\[10pt]
= {} & 2^{8+18-20}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Too complicated. Notice that:

- $16 = 2^4$;
- $64 = 2^6$;
- $1024 = 2^{10}$.

Therefore:

$$\begin{array}[rcl]
((16^{2} \times 64^{3})\div 1024^{2} & = & (2^{8} \times 2^{18})\div 2^{20} \\
& = & 2^{26}\div 2^{20} = 2^6 = 64. \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 4):

By writing these out as powers of primes (namely $2$), we have
$$
\frac{16^{2} \times 64^{3}}{1024^{2}} = \frac{(2^{4})^{2} \times (2^{6})^{3}}{(2^{10})^{2}} = \frac{2^{8}\times2^{18}}{2^{20}} = \frac{2^{26}}{2^{20}} = 2^{6}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that all can be represented in powers of 2

$$16^2=(2^4)^2=2^8$$
$$64^3=(2^6)^3=2^{18}$$
$$1024^2=(2^{10})^2=2^{20}$$
$$\frac{2^8\cdot 2^{18}}{2^{20}}=\frac{2^{26}}{2^{20}}=2^6$$

Answer (score 3):

$$(16^{2} \times 64^{3})\div1024^{2}=2^8 \times 2^{18} /2^{20} =2^6=64$$