# Question on "Proof by contradiction"

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I am a little confused whether the following set of arguments can constitute a proof by contradiction:

Required to prove: Statement **A** is true.

Assumption: Suppose statement **A** is false.

We then show that if **A** is false then a (different) statement **B** is true.

But, statement **B** is true implies **A** is true.

Hence, **A** must be true.

These set of arguments feel a bit bizzare to me and perhaps might be incorrect. I am unable find a mistake.

Comment: If $\mathbf A$ is false then $\mathbf A$ is true, that's a contradiction. Do you have an actual proof that you feel unsure?

Comment: Yes, such a proof would be fine.

Comment: @peterwhy Yes, I did have an actual proof. The proof comes from algebraic geometry and is quite technical. I managed to reduce it to statements A and B as above and check the individual steps as written above. I had previously not seen this usage of proof by contradiction, so I wanted to be sure., if it is OK.

Comment: @JairTaylor Thanks

Comment: Also take a look at [Point 3 here and its footnote](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4216087/21813), which I wrote two days ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start your proof from "let **A** be false". Now, using "true tools" you prove a particular statement which implies that **A** has to be true. So to sum up you prove that **A** is false implies **A** is true. This is a contradiction. For example:

**A**: there *isn't* a smallest rational number greater than zero.

Assumption: there *is* a smallest rational number greater than zero.

So, call him $r$.

Now you can take $r/2$.

So **B**: given a rational number $r$ greater than zero, there exists another rational number $r/2$ that is greater than zero and smaller than $r$.

So **A**.

Comment: Thanks. The example helps a lot.

Comment: "you prove that **A** is false implies **A** is true. This is a contradiction" No it isn't, it is a (supposedly) valid implication that one could deduce at this point, but in fact one doesn't. Instead, but proving, under the assumption that **A** is false, that **A** is true you have arrived at a point where, by using the assumption a (supposedly) second time, one can easily derive a contradiction (still under that assumption). Then one can proceed with the proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

This technique is actually quite common.  The answer above from LuckyS is a nice one.  Here's my favorite simple example.

- We have three beans, each one either white or black.
- We will prove that there must a pair of beans of the same color.
- Suppose this is not so.
- Then the first two beans are not a pair of the same color, so one is white and the other is black.
- Then if the third bean is white, there is a pair of white beans, and if the third bean is black, there is a pair of black beans.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a proof by contradiction, but written in a different way.

You have two statements: $B \implies A$ and $\neg A \implies B$, both of which are true.

If you have come across [proofs by contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive) before, you will know that $B \implies A$ and $\neg A \implies \neg B$ are equivalent. This means that what you really have are the two statements

$$\neg A \implies B \\ \neg A \implies \neg B$$

This is a contradiction, and this is how one typically learns proofs by contradiction. So what you have is essentially the same thing, but with the second statement $\neg A \implies \neg B$ written as the equivalent $B \implies A$.

Comment: @Chen To be extremely clear, the pair of highlighted statements aren't in themselves a contradiction, but they *lead to* the contradiction $(B$ and $\lnot B)$ — and only when $\lnot A$ is true (in this case, presumed to be true).  If, instead, $A$ is true, the pair of highlighted statements don't lead to any contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

(Posted after a previous answer was accepted.)

We have the tautology:

[image]

We can verify this using a truth table. Or we can can prove it using a simplified form of natural deduction as below. We take the negation of proposition $A$ on line 4 to mean that "$A$ is assumed to be false" (a premise). Lines 4-9 are a proof by contradiction that $A$ must be true given the premise on line 1. (Screenshot from my proof checker)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The way proof by contradiction works is that by assuming **A** is false, we can find some logical reasoning that shows that some *known false* statement **B** is true.  Sometimes the key to a proof is that the false statement **B** is "**A** ^ ¬**A**", but it doesn't need to be that: **B** could be "1 = 2" or any other false statement.

Then, having shown that assuming ¬**A** means that the false statement **B** actually is true, we state that this is absurd, and conclude that ¬**A** must actually be false.  Since ¬**A** is false, **A** must be true.